# very simple final modifier and run method issue

Tags: java

i have a simple question about the modifier "final" and the var being used in the run() method. here is a piece of some code that i have but the else doesn't work. i guess it cant add onto the firstTime var, im not sure if this is because you cant do this with final modifiers or if java just hates me  :/

```
final long firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

WorldTasksManager.schedule(new WorldTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= firstTime) {
        stop();
    } else {
    firstTime += 5;
    }
}
```

if you guys know whats causing this or how i can fix this, please help.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Final variables cannot be modified.  That is (essentially) the definition of final.

You can't change the reference, but you can mutate the object.  However, in the case of `long` like you have here, a new `long` is created and assigned to the value of `firstTime`, which is attempting to change the reference and thereby illegal.

Comment: when I tried to remove the final modifier I got another error. to fix it all I had to do was declare the long, firstTime, inside worldtask and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

A final variable can only be assigned in the constructor or at declaration time through an initializer.

Comment: He can't remove final in this case (anonymous class).

Answer (score 1):

This SO Q&A explains the compilation error you got when you removed the `final` modifier:

- [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

In your example, the `firstTime` that the `run()` variable sees is actually a *copy* of the `firstTime` variable in the enclosing class.  The `final` is required to preserve the illusion that there is only one variable ...

Your solution of moving the declaration of `firstTime` into the `run()` method is good, but it does change the behaviour.  The variable is now set to the time when the task starts running, were previously it was set to the time when the task was scheduled.

Finally, if you really want the `run()` method to be able to update the `firstTime` variable in the enclosing scope, you are going to need to do this some other way.  This simplest way would be to make `firstTime` an instance variable, not a local variable.  You could then remove the `final` and the `run()` method could update the variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like

```
WorldTasksManager.schedule(new WorldTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
    long firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= firstTime) {
        stop();
    } else {
    firstTime += 5;
    }
}
```